# Smooth bitmap movement in canvas (android)

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, ondraw

I tried to create a Maze with a moving ball and a hole using the Accelerometer Sensor. With the following code, the ball falls into the hole, but the performance is really bad, I set the Accelerometer Frequency to the fastest, but it's everything other than smooth. I made a second canvas, because so I could make a hole.

```
public RenderView(Context context, int width, int height) {
    super(context);
    playGround = new Rect(40, 40, width - 40, height - 40);
    holes.addElement(new PointF(500f, 500f));

    // Set background
    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom);

    // Set bitmap
    woodGround= wood.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
    bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(woodGround);

    // Set eraser paint properties
    eraserPaint.setAlpha(0);
    eraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    eraserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
            | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    if (ballInHole)
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, b.x, b.y, paint);

    bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(wall, 0, 0, paint);
    bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(wood, playGround, playGround, paint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    for (PointF h : holes) {
        bitmapCanvas.drawCircle(h.x + radius, h.y + radius, radius,
                eraserPaint);
    }
    if (!ballInHole)
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, b.x, b.y, paint);
    invalidate();
}
```

It's solved very ugly, because I just draw the ball bellow the other bitmaps when he falls into a hole. Is there another way to do it?

The performance is also really bad, i set the Accelerometer-Sensor-Delay to the fastest, but the ball doesn't run smooth. When I remove the line `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);`, then the ball is smoother, but then the wooden background is away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're doing A LOT of drawings all the time and that's take time to draw and the performance gets very low.

here a few tips on how you should approach it.

You probably better have one view with the static stuff (the background image and the holes) and on your layout have a second view on top of it just drawing the ball.

on the background image, do not call invalidate. That way you will draw the background just once.

and the top image (the ball only) you can invalidate, so it can redraw on the new position.

I'm not sure on this last part: but you may need to call `invalidate(rect);` passing the area where the ball was on the previous time, to make the background only re-draw that small area (instead of the whole screen)

happy coding.

Comment: It worked, I splitted it into different views, thanks! Now it's much smoother.